# How Can I Pass A Parameter From A DetailView To An UpdateView?

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to pass a parameter from a DetailView to an UpdateView if the user clicks on a button.  I've done this with other views, createview and updateview, but can't quite work out how to do this from a DetailView to an UpdateView.

In my DetailView, I have an HTML button on the View that looks something like..

```
<button type="submit" name="status" value="cancel"></button>
```

I am trying to pass the cancel value to the UpdateView....

I have tried to override POST as shown below:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if "cancel" in request.POST:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Book:author_menu'))
    else:
        return super(BookView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

However when I do this it says method is not allowed.

I also played around a bit with get_object....And while it does allow me to get the existing values...I can't seem to get the passed value...

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = super(BookView, self).get_object(queryset=queryset)
    return obj
```

I am trying to update/feed the cancel parameter to the UpdateView and then do something. Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: your problem maybe in `request.POST`. You value `cancel` not inside this direct(maybe inside attribue `status`). Can you debug and show data of `request.POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately changed the view to an UpdateView and got the data I needed from the view.  Was a simpler approach.